# Dividing non-zero elements using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A`. I would like to divide the non-zero elements and obtain a new array `B`. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[0,1,2],[4,0,8],[7,5,0]])
print([A])
```

The desired output is

```
B=[array([[0,1/1,1/2],[1/4,0,1/8],[1/7,1/5,0]])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (you will get a `RuntimeWarning` though):

```
B = np.where(A, 1/A, 0)
```

or [`numpy.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html):

```
B = np.divide(1, A, out=np.zeros_like(A, dtype=float), where=A!=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

With NumPy arrays, it's simple:

```
A = np.array([[0,1,2],[4,0,8],[7,5,0]])
# Create an array with zeroes with the same shape as A
B = np.zeros(A.shape)
# Update elements in B that are non-zero in A
B[A != 0] = 1/A[A != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
try:
   B = A/2
except:
   pass
```